# PHPMotion implementation - URL based videos (Hosted on separate location)

Tags: phpmotion

I have to implement a video collection website for users of a specific ISP. The site will be hosted on a public web-server but all the movies will be hosted on local ISP server. The user of that ISP + general visitors can see the available movies; but only ISP's users will be able to play them.
The player on site will point to URL of a local machine (http://192.x.x.x/movies/mymovie.mov) this private class (192.x.x.x) will only be accessible to ISP user.

**Question:** Is it possible with PHPMotion script? or I need to do custom work.
If possible, can someone please suggest available MODs?

Comment: This should rather be done at network/web server configuration level I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPmotion would require some modifications to be able to handle something like this.  Uploading, conversion, thumbnail generation, and playback are all pretty static in PHPmotion.

Really though, rather than modding the entire upload and conversion process, if you created a quick custom form to add entries to the PHPmotion database (maybe include thumbnail upload), then tweaked the playback paths, you should be good to go on the PHPmotion side of things.  This would assume that you already had your videos in a format that the player could handle (such as flv or mp4).